# How do I restore pip after upgrade from ver 9 to ver 18 on Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop Vm?

Tags: pip, python-2.7

I started with pip ver 9, and after reading a blog how to upgrade, I ran following which seems to have broken pip:

```
# pip install --upgrade pip
```

This installed pip ver 18 !!

```
Successfully installed pip-18.0
```

After this, pip won't run with following error:
e.g.

```
# pip --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name main
```

i) I've removed pip and reinstalled it as follows but no success:

```
# sudo apt-get remove python-pip
# sudo apt purge python-pip
# which pip
! pip is not found

# sudo apt install python-pip
```

After reinstalling from the above, any pip commands *still* fail with the same error as before...

ii) I've run this command and it finds the install package is still on the system:

```
# python2.7 -m pip --version
pip 18.0 from /home/person/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)

# ll /home/person/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
<snip>
drwxr-xr-x  4 person person    4096 Aug  1 13:12 pip/

drwxr-xr-x  2 person person    4096 Aug  1 13:12 pip-18.0.dist-info/
```

Q: How do I restore back to pip ver 9.x ??  Reinstalling doesn't seem to work ?

Q: Do I have to remove python2.7 as well, and reinstall both (which I don't want to do unless necessary) ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to remove python2.7 as well. Create a symbolic link at `/home/person/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip` which references to file `/usr/bin/pip`. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python-pip # installs version 9.0.1
cd /home/person/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/  
rm -r pip  
which pip # check pip location
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/pip /home/person/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip # /usr/bin/pip may be /usr/local/bin/pip for some users
```

Check to see if pip 9.0.1 is installed.

```
python2.7 -m pip --version
```

Comment: Thank you @karel !!  This worked with some minor tweaks (rm -r pip, and path for last line needed updating). So:  

! installs pip version 9.0.1  
sudo apt install python-pip  
cd /home/person/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/  
  
! remove pip directory  
rm -r pip  

! check pip location  
which pip  

sudo ln -s /usr/bin/pip /home/person/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip

Comment: @ck2017 updated